# in vuetify component scrolling is not displaying properly

Tags: vuetify.js, v-dialog

[Image of my v-dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSvRB.png)

I have an issue in scroll. I'm using a Vuetify component. when a v-dialog opens it's scroll is working but scroll is not showing up. scrolling place is transparent

scrolling is working but is not showing in the right of dialog properly [There is a image of my dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2S7Z.png).

Comment: apply CSS [overflow-y: scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)